# Removing multiple items from a Grails One to Many relationship

Tags: grails, many-to-many

I'm creating an application using `Grails 2.2.4`  and `Java 7` (these are constraints I cannot change) and I run into an odd behavior when trying to delete multiple entries in a Many-To-Many hasMany Set.

I have a class named `Sport` that contains the following:

```
    Class Sport{
    String name
    static hasMany=[category:Category]
    static belongsTo = [Category]
    }
```

And another one named `Category`:

```
    Class Category{
    String name
    static hasMany=[sports:Sport]
    }
```

Now when in my `CategoryController` I try to delete multiple `Sport` instances from `sports`, my code compiles and runs without errors, but for reason only one of the selected instances is actually deleted.

If I get a `Sport` list and a `Category` id from a form and try to run the following code on every objet in the list:

```
    def categoryInstance = Category.get(idCategory)
    def sportInstance = Sport.get(idSport)
    if(sportInstance!=null){
        categoryInstance.removeFromSports(sportInstance)
    }
     categoryInstance.save()
```

Only the last instance is deleted.

If I run

```
    def categoryInstance = Category.get(idCategory)
    def sportInstance = Sport.get(idSport)
    if(sportInstance!=null){
        categoryInstance.removeFromSports(sportInstance)
     categoryInstance.save()
     }
```

Only the first one is deleted.

Note that this code is run from within a `for` loop over the `params.sport.toList()` list.

My guess is that this is either due to the fact that my sports Set is somehow "changed" after the first deletion and therefore Hibernate can't find the next instance, or that my save method commits the first change then "forgets" the next.

Any advice on how I can delete more than one instance at a time?

Comment: Read this post it should help http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not trying to delete the actual sport in the database, only the relationship between a category and (more than) one of the related sports.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to wrap the code for deleting a single association in a block of withNewSession + withNewTransaction

```
Sport.withNewSession {
    Sport.withNewTransaction {
        //delete 1 association here
    }
}
```

It's not very elegant but works. Beware of a potential performance impact, as this will likely have many database roundtrips. 
I don't know why this problem occurs, and googling didn't help either.

Another solution = workaround is to explicitly map the relationship as SportCategory, which you can then delete like any other object with SportCategory.delete().